# View Transition where view has constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uikit-dynamics

I am creating a custom view transition where the view controller being presented swings down, using a UIDynamicAnimator. The animation works in swinging the entire view down, except when I move the toView up off the screen in preparation for swinging, all the subviews move due to their position constraints, altering the view.

To avoid this, could I either make a copy of the entire view controller to use or stop the subviews from Autolayouting?

Comment: Simple answer: don't do that. Animation and constraints are opposites. You can't have both (unless what you animate _is_ the constraints).

Comment: animate a view by updating value of its constraints not view directly

Comment: I am moving the entire view in a transition from one view to another, not moving subviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was one of my constraints was to the Top Layout Guide, meaning when I moved the VC, it moved all the views within. I fixed this by making the constraint based off of the superview, and all works perfectly.